# Nhibernate map by code parent/child/collection insert issues

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Currently I have a problem with NHibernate and mapping my schema by code.
See [Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MovzI.jpg) to find out what I'm trying to map.

- One category has at least one language representation
- One category has 0 or more products
- One product has at least one language representation
- A product always belongs to a category

Here is the code which I use to map these entities.

**CategoryMap**

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityMapping<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap() : base("Category")
    {
        Property(p => p.Status, c =>
          {
              c.Column("Status");
          });

        Set(p => p.CategoryRepresentations, c =>
            {
                c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                c.Access(Accessor.NoSetter);
                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("CategoryId");
                    k.NotNullable(true);
                });
                c.Cascade(Cascade.All.Exclude(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));                    
            }, o => o.OneToMany());

        Set(p => p.Products, c =>
            {
                c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Extra);
                c.Access(Accessor.NoSetter);
                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("CategoryId");
                    k.NotNullable(true);
                });
                c.Cascade(Cascade.All.Exclude(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));                    
            }, o => o.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

**CategoryRepresentationMap**

```
public class CategoryRepresentationMap : EntityMapping<CategoryRepresentation>
{
    public CategoryRepresentationMap() : base("CategoryRepresentation")
    {
        Property(p=>p.Language, c =>
        {
            c.Column("Language");
        });

        Property(p=>p.RepresentationText, c =>
        {
            c.Column("RepresentationText");
            c.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
        });
    }
}
```

**ProductMap**

```
public class ProductMap : EntityMapping<Product>
{
    public ProductMap() : base("Product")
    {
        Property(p => p.Status, c =>
        {
            c.Column("Status");
        });

        Set(p => p.ProductRepresentations, c =>
        {
            c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
            c.Access(Accessor.NoSetter);
            c.Key(k =>
            {
                k.Column("ProductId");
                k.NotNullable(true);
            });
            c.Cascade(Cascade.All.Exclude(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));
            c.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join);
        }, o => o.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

**ProductRepresentationMap**

```
public class ProductRepresentationMap : EntityMapping<ProductRepresentation>
{
    public ProductRepresentationMap() : base("ProductRepresentation")
    {
        Property(p => p.Language, c =>
        {
            c.Column("Language");
        });

        Property(p => p.RepresentationText, c =>
        {
            c.Column("RepresentationText");
            c.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
        });
    }
}
```

**EntityMapping**

```
public abstract class EntityMapping<TEntity> : ClassMapping<TEntity>
    where TEntity:Entity<long>
{
    protected EntityMapping(string tableName)
    {
        Id(i=>i.Id, c =>
        {
            c.Column("Id");
            c.Generator(Generators.Identity);
            c.Type(NHibernateUtil.Int64);
        });
        Table(tableName);
        DynamicInsert(true);
        DynamicUpdate(true);
    }
}
```

**Category**

```
public class Category : Entity<long>
{
    protected Category()
    {
        _categoryRepresentations=new List<CategoryRepresentation>();
        _products=new List<Product>();
    }

    public static Category Create(Status status, List<CategoryRepresentation> categoryRepresentations)
    {
        var category = new Category()
        {
            Status = status
        };

        foreach (var categoryRepresentation in categoryRepresentations)
        {
            category._categoryRepresentations.Add(categoryRepresentation);
        }

        return category;
    }

    public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        _products.Add(product);
    }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    private readonly ICollection<CategoryRepresentation> _categoryRepresentations;
    public virtual IEnumerable<CategoryRepresentation> CategoryRepresentations
    {
        get
        {
            return _categoryRepresentations;
        }
    }

    private readonly ICollection<Product> _products;

    public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _products;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add products to my category I'll get this excepction:

```
    NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not insert: [Catalog.Product][SQL: /* insert Catalog.Product */ INSERT INTO Product (Status, CategoryId) VALUES (?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "", table "Category", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Anyone familiar with this problem? What am I missing here? I read several questions and answers but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved since it was an issue in combination of issues with nunit tests and resharper 10.01. Updating to 10.02 solved it.